# Structural directive's context not updated

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have created a structural directive with context.

```
@Directive({selector: '[myDir]'})
export class MyDir implements OnInit {
  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
              private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
  ) { }

  public context = {$implicit: false}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, this.context)
  }
}
```

This is how I use it.

```
<pre *myDir="let context">Context: {{ context | json}}</pre>
```

The template is properly installed into the view and `Context: false` is present as expected.

However, if I try to change the context, it's **not reflected in the view**. Judging by [`ngTemplateOutlet` spec from the Angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/685cc26ab2dc7f8d836ec932a43d45edfa0f8e97/packages/common/test/directives/ng_template_outlet_spec.ts#L94-L104), it looks like it should be updated when the context changes. **Is there mistake in my code, or am I misinterpreting the spec?**

I've also tried injecting CR and manually triggering change detection, but it didn't work. In my real case, the change was supposed to be triggered on observable subscription which listens to mouse events, but here's a demo with simple interval.

```
Observable
  .interval(500)
  .map((_, i) => i % 2 == 0)
  .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  .subscribe(context => {
    this.context = {$implicit: context}
    console.log('Context is now', this.context.$implicit)
  })
```

Although `context$` **does** change, and the changes **are** shown in the console, the view doesn't update. [Here's a **demo** on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-context-question?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

---

I've added unsubscribing on destroy because otherwise the Blitz goes mad after a few reloadings. Also added a test observable which is just a simple counter of half-second intervals to the AppComponent, unrelated to the directive. This is just a sanity check the the app is working and CD cycle is generally running on the whole app properly. I do not use OnPush anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is very intreresting language.

Let's consider the following code:

```typescript
let view: any = {};
function detectChanges() {
  console.log(view.context);
}

function createEmbeddedView(context) {
  view.context = context;
}

let context = { x: false };
createEmbeddedView(context);

detectChanges(); // prints { x: false }
```

when we create `context` and passed it to `createEmbeddedView` function.

Now let's change `context`. We will do it two options:

1) change itself

```typescript
context = { x: true };

detectChanges(); // prints { x: false }
```

2) change INTERNALS

```typescript
context.x = true;

detectChanges(); // prints { x: true} Hooray!!!
```

As we can see our output is not changed in first case while it works in the second case. That's because in javascript we pass object [by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

It's  a specific kind of pass-by-value. If we change parameter itself it will not have any effect to the item that was fed inside function. But if we change some of properties then it will change the item.

So for your case you could change your context like:

```typescript
this.context.$implicit = context;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-context-question-a4n5yx?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Ah, sometimes I get caught up in Angular and RxJS so much I forget basics of JavaScript.

This also explains why it works in tests: they are testing the _template_ version of this with `ngTemplateOutlet`, which means the same reference is passed on every CD cycle. In my case, CD can't work it out because there's simply no way to know that those two object should stay in sync.

Comment: @yurzui, correct me if i'm wrong. If context is replaced with new reference it won't detect changes, but if the last key (*last key i mean, key which points to primitive value*) value is changed it works.
 (a) ```var ref = this.templatePortal.context;```
 (a) ```ref.addr.x = "100";```

(b) ```this.templatePortal.context = { addr: { x: 520 } };```
 ***a*** works but ***b*** doesn't. 
 But in other cases actual reference has to be changed for ngOnChanges to be called, which is one of the example. Can you provide some insight into it.